# Boundary value spaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

In Uhlenbecks paper [Connections with $L^p$ bounds on curvature](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103920743) [p.38, l. 2-4] it is noted that a certain boundary value problem may be solved by using "boundary value spaces". A [book of Katrin Wehrheim](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=rVQRSiOQeKkC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=katrin%20wehrheim&ots=QWAnHWaJ_M&sig=MVaiLwO64L0qc318ZIwIWEuYkQs#v=onepage&q=katrin%20wehrheim&f=false) uses the same notion, although I was not able to find an explicit definition anywhere. As far as my guess goes, the main idea lies in formulating a boundary value problem as a question on an operator with e.g. range $L^2(\Omega) \times L^2(\partial\Omega)$, where the second factor is the *boundary value space*.

**Question**: What is meant by *boundary value spaces* and what are their advantages when it comes to boundary value problems?